How can I change firefox bundle id so I can choose the correct default browser?
I have two versions of Firefox installed (regular 126 and beta 129) to help me switch between my work and my private user profile.
Both installations show me "Firefox is set as default browser". In the system setting I tried switching back and forth (and even temporary switched to another browser), but still it opens all links in the beta version and not in the regular browser.
According to this answer, the problem occurs, because all Firefox installations use the same bundle id and mac chooses the newest version when there are multiple versions available.
So I was wondering how I can force one of those two versions to identify with another bundle id? I thought the beta once had org.mozilla.firefoxbeta instead of org.mozilla.firefox ?
Or do you have other solutions how to switch the default browser between multiple installed versions?
